# Chromium: "Running without the SUID sandbox!" error

Tags: chromium

I've downloaded and unpacked a fresh copy of Chromium (Linux_x64), and when I try to run the `chrome` binary, this happens:

```
[23986:23986:0806/143027:FATAL:browser_main_loop.cc(148)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It doesn't happen with Ubuntu's `chromium-browser` package. I can bypass the error by running Chromium with `--no-sandbox` but I'd rather leave the sandbox enabled.

`chrome_sandbox` has permissions `4755` and is executable by `chrome`. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

It might not be related, but I'm using full-disk encryption on my Ubuntu install.

Comment: Try to use the version from the repos. Don't download random stuff from the net.

Answer (score 14):

Download `chrome-linux.zip` from appropriate folder from [here](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html).

Extract the file - will get a folder called `chrome-linux`.

Move the folder to wherever you want - I move it to my home folder.

- navigate to that folder
- open a terminal there

Previous two step might be reversed.

Run these four commands individually:

```
sudo mv chrome_sandbox chrome-sandbox
sudo chown root chrome-sandbox
sudo chmod 4755 chrome-sandbox
./chrome-wrapper
```

When I do that, I am good to go.

Answer (score 6):

Do:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0 && ./chrome --no-sandbox
```

Comment: Does not help. Check for yourself: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/Linux_x64/382014/chrome-linux.zip

Answer (score 1):

Development of chrome sandbox stopped early 2016 (latest version of chrome-linux (64bit) that Lyle mentioned is http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/382014/ which is from March 2016, more than a year ago).

See the comment at the TOP of https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md which refers to the discussion here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=598454 -- a bug that was closed as Fixed on 21 June 2016.

That discussion seems to indicate that with the appropriate kernel support it is safe to run chrome with --disable-setuid-sandbox which should cause chrome to stop even looking for the sandbox, but refuse to run if your kernel hasn't got the support to safely do so.

Nevertheless, at this moment (April 2017) ubuntu Stable (Xenial) still comes with the sandbox; package chromium-browser contains: /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome-sandbox which is setuid root.
The reason that I did got the error in the title of this question is that I was running a special version of chrome that was part of a package that came with an application (a SecondLife viewer) that found it necessary to provide their own version of the browser. Needless to say that this downloaded package wasn't installed with setuid root :p (nor would I suggest to change it to 4755, because that doesn't sound very secure to do).

Answer (score 0):

On an Ubuntu 13.04 computer, the executable **chromium-browser-sandbox** has the file permission **4755** and is owned by **root**

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -l /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-sandbox
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 13904 Jul 18 16:11 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-sandbox
```

I guess you need to use the command `chown root.root /path/to/chrome_sandbox` to make **root** the owner of the executable.

Comment: Not working keep saying [3695:3695:1128/164126:FATAL:browser_main_loop.cc(167)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem Running without the SUID sandbox! See code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment I do the next steps...

install chrome-linux http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html?prefix=Linux_x64/100056/ (X64)

unzip the zip, execute the commands and enter to folder

```
sudo mv chrome_sandbox chrome-sandbox
sudo chown root chrome-sandbox
sudo chmod 4755 chrome-sandbox
```

then, I unzip and install libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u6_amd64.deb from this command

```
wget http://security.debian.org/debian- 
security/pool/updates/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u6_amd64.deb
```

Then execute the commands individually:

```
mv libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u6_amd64.deb ../
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u6_amd64.deb
./chrome-wrapper
```